# Type-ahead plugin not recognizing POST response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, spring-boot

My Spring-boot POST endpoint returns data that does not work with the [type ahead plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md) I am using. It works when I use GET.

This GET endpoint works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/station", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Station> getstation() {
    List<Station> listStation = stationService.findAll();
    return listStation;
}
```

with this javascript:

```
    $.get("/station", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("[name='query']").typeahead({
        source: data,
        minLength: 3
    });
}, 'json');
```

The data returned looks like `[{id:123,name:"ABC"}]`.

If I try using POST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findstation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Station> findstation(@RequestBody Station jsonSearchString) {
    List<Station> listStation = stationService.stationContaining(jsonSearchString.getName());
    return listStation;
}
```

with javascript:

```
    $('#queryStation').keyup(function() {
    console.log("in change function statoion oc");
    var stationName = $(this).val();
    if(stationName.length==3){
        console.log("the length statement is true");
        ajax_search(stationName);
    }
});

function ajax_search(stationName){
    console.log("search function value " +stationName);
    var stationJson = '{ "name":"' +stationName+ '"}'
    $.ajax ({
        url: "/findstation",
        type: "POST",
        data: stationJson,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;",
        success: function(data){
        console.log("inside success handler");
            stationTypeahead(data);
        }
    });
}

function stationTypeahead(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#queryStation').typeahead({
        source: data
    });
}
```

Returns JSON like `[{id:123, name:"LAX"}]` - which does not seem to work with the plugin. `typeof data;` returns object.

If I hard code, for example `data = [{"id":123,"name":"ABC"}]` this works with the plugin.

I am pretty sure the HTML is fine as it works with GET.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Typeof is `object` for both POST and GET.

Comment: What is your post response content type?. And if you think that it's expecting a string why not just do JSON.stringify on the response and then pass to typeahead. And also what is "typeof data;" for the GET call

Comment: @karthick you mean post response content type set on POST controller? I posted controller.

Comment: Question is more like what is the content-type you see in the response header? Sometimes there are chances that the call may be expecting a json and you might be setting the content type as text.

Comment: The data comes back fine. It's in some format. Just not working with plugin.

Comment: Can't see anywhere where you're making a POST request to `/findstation`

Comment: Good spotting. Edited. Not the issue however.

Comment: You're still using `GET`. You would need to use `url: '/findstation', method: 'POST'`. It's also a bad idea to try and create your own JSON string. Use `stationJson = JSON.stringify({ name: stationName })`

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the wrong code initially.

Comment: Use your browser's _Network_ console to debug the problem on the client-side.

Comment: @phil why did you mark as duplicate? The other answer deals with data being sent to the server? This is different as it deals with data back from the server.

Comment: @Phil please re-open so I can post answer which is different to other question and will help others.

Comment: I've re-opened it but you should show that you're actually POST-ing the correct data to your backend. When I closed this, you were still using a GET request to the wrong URL. Please show some screenshots from your browser's _Network_ console showing the POST request, the request body and the response

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code to:

```
function stationTypeahead(data){
    $("[name='query']").typeahead({
        source: data,
        minLength: 2
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="queryStation" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
</div>
```

I don't know why, but when I targeted the [typeahead plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md) using a jquery name attribute for the selector it worked. There was nothing wrong with the object returned from the server.